# Input bugando sem motivo

Tags: c++, algoritmo, classificação, algoritmo-de-busca

Eu fiz um programa que computa (por um DB próprio usando `fstream`) pacientes de um hospital. Ele tem funções para output (um só para ostream usando o `iomanip` e outro para `ofstream` e `fstream`) e input (`get()`). Como exigência, tive que usar o *selection sort* e o *binary search* que gastam uma memória danada (pelo menos do jeito que tive que fazer o binary search), além de carregar os dados de maneira bruta. Implementei os seguintes:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
class patientType
{
    private:
    char* first_name_t;
    char* second_name_t;
    unsigned id_t;
    public:
    patientType()
    {
    }
    void get()
    {
        char* first_name = new char[128];
        char* second_name = new char[128];
        unsigned id;
        std::cout << "\nType patient's first name: ";
        std::cin >> first_name;
        std::cout << "\nType patient's second name: ";
        std::cin >> second_name;
        std::cout << "\nType patient's ID: ";
        std::cin >> id;
        std::cout << std::endl;
        this->first_name_t = new char[std::strlen(first_name)];
        std::strcpy(this->first_name_t, first_name);
        delete first_name;
        this->second_name_t = new char[std::strlen(second_name)];
        std::strcpy(this->second_name_t, second_name);
        delete second_name;
        this->id_t = id;
    }
    patientType(const char* first_name, const char* second_name, const unsigned id)
    {
        this->first_name_t = new char[std::strlen(first_name)];
        std::strcpy(this->first_name_t, first_name);
        this->second_name_t = new char[std::strlen(second_name)];
        std::strcpy(this->second_name_t, second_name);
        this->id_t = (unsigned)id;
    }
    ~patientType() //De
    {
        this->id_t = 0;
        delete[] this->first_name_t;
        delete[] this->second_name_t;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, patientType& patient)
    {
        os << patient.first_name() << std::left << std::setw(3) << ' ' << patient.second_name() << std::left << std::setw(3) << ' ' << patient.id() << std::endl;
        return os;
    }
    void save(std::ofstream& ofs)
    {
         ofs << this->first_name() << "\t" << this->second_name() << "\t" << this->id() << "\n";
    }
    void save(std::fstream& ofs)
    {
        ofs << this->first_name() << "\t" << this->second_name() << "\t" << this->id() << "\n";
    }
    void operator=(const patientType& patient)
    {
        this->first_name_t = new char[std::strlen(patient.first_name_t)];
        std::strcpy(this->first_name_t, patient.first_name_t);
        this->second_name_t = new char[std::strlen(patient.second_name_t)];
        std::strcpy(this->second_name_t, patient.second_name_t);
        this->id_t = (unsigned)patient.id_t;
    }
    const char* first_name() {return const_cast<const char*>(this->first_name_t);}
    const char* second_name() {return const_cast<const char*>(this->second_name_t);}
    const unsigned id() {return (const unsigned)id_t;}
};
#include <vector>
template<class T> std::vector<unsigned> binary_search(T* var, T term, unsigned size)
{
    std::vector<unsigned> ret;
    unsigned mid = size / 2;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < mid; i++) {if(var[i] == term) ret.push_back(i);}
    for(unsigned i = mid; i < size; i++) {if(var[i] == term) ret.push_back(i);}
    return ret;
}

template<class T, class BinaryCompare> std::vector<unsigned> binary_search(T* var, T term, unsigned size, BinaryCompare compare_operation)
{
    std::vector<unsigned> ret;
    unsigned mid = size / 2;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < mid; i++) {if(compare_operation(var[i],term)) ret.push_back(i);}
    for(unsigned i = mid; i < size; i++) {if(compare_operation(var[i],term)) ret.push_back(i);}
    return ret;
}
template <typename T> void swap(T& var, T& var1)
{
    T temp = var;
    var = var1;
    var1 = temp;
}
template <typename T> void selection_sort(T* var, unsigned size, unsigned pos = 0) //1 3 5 2 4; tamanho 5
{
    if(!(pos >= size))
    {
        for(int i = pos+1; i < size; i++)
        {
            if(var[pos] > var[i]) swap(var[pos], var[i]);
        }
        selection_sort(var, size, pos+1);
    }
    else return;
}
template <typename T, typename BinaryCompare>void selection_sort(T* var, unsigned size, BinaryCompare compare_operation, unsigned pos = 0)
{
    if(!(pos >= size))
    {
        for(int i = pos+1; i < size; i++)
        {
            if(compare_operation(var[pos], var[i])) swap(var[pos], var[i]);
        }
        selection_sort(var, size, compare_operation, pos+1);
    }
    else return;
}
```

Então eu fiz o main():

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "patientType.hpp"
#include "search.hpp"
#include "sort.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

bool file_exists(const char* file)
{
    std::ifstream file_(file);
    if(!file_.good() || file_.fail() || file_.bad()) return false; else return true;
}
bool empty_file(const char* file)
{
    std::ifstream file_(file);
    return file_.peek() == std::ifstream::traits_type::eof();
}

int main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        unsigned option = 0;
        if(!file_exists("patient.db") || empty_file("patient.db"))
        {
            std::ofstream file("patient.db");
            std::cout << "1. Add patient\n";
            std::cout << "2. Exit\n> ";
            std::cin >> option;
            switch(option)
            {
                case 1:{patientType patient; patient.get(); patient.save(file); break;}
                case 2: {exit(0);break;}
                default: {std::cout << "Input a valid option.\n";break;}
            }
        }
        else
        {
            std::string file_content;
            std::fstream file("patient.db");
            unsigned file_size = 0;
            while(std::getline(file, file_content)) {if(!file_content.empty()) file_size++;}
            file.close();
            file.open("patient.db");
            patientType* patients = new patientType[file_size];
            int instance = 0;
            while(std::getline(file, file_content))
            {
                std::string params[3];
                std::stringstream A(file_content);
                for(int i = 0; std::getline(A, file_content, '\t');) {if(!file_content.empty()){params[i] = file_content;i++;}}
                patientType A_(params[0].c_str(), params[1].c_str(), std::stoi(params[2]));
                patients[instance] = A_;
                instance++;
            }
            std::cout << "1. Print patient\n2. Add a patient\n3. Sort patients by last name\n4. Sort patients by ID\n5. Search patient by last name\n6. Search patient by ID\n7. Exit the program\n> ";
            std::cin >> option;
            switch(option)
            {
                case 1:
                {
                    unsigned index;
                    std::cout << "\nSelect index (in range 1 to " << file_size << ").\n> ";
                    std::cin>> index;
                    if(index < 1 || index > file_size)
                    {
                        exit(-1);
                    }
                    else std::cout <<"\n" << std::left << "1st name" << std::left << std::setw(3) << " 2nd name" << std::left << std::setw(3) << " ID\n" << patients[index - 1] << "\n";
                    break;
                }
                case 2:
                {
                    file.close();
                    patientType patient;
                    patient.get();
                    std::ofstream file_("patient.db", std::ios::app);
                    patient.save(file_);
                    break;
                }
                case 3:
                {
                    selection_sort(patients, file_size, [](patientType& first, patientType& second){return first.second_name() > second.second_name();});
                    break;
                }
                case 4:
                {
                    selection_sort(patients, file_size, [](patientType& first, patientType& second){return first.id() > second.id();});
                    break;
                }
                case 5:
                {
                    unsigned term;
                    std::cout << "Input the ID term: ";
                    std::cin >> term;
                    std::vector<unsigned> occurrences = binary_search(patients, patientType("","",term), file_size, [](patientType& first, patientType& second){return first.id() == second.id();});
                    std::cout << "Found " << occurrences.size() << " occurrences.\n";
                    for(auto a : occurrences)
                    {
                        std::cout << patients[a];
                        std::cout << "\nAt " << a << "\n";
                    }
                    std::cout << std::endl;
                    break;
                }
                case 6:
                {
                    char* term = new char[128];
                    std::cout << "Input the last name term: ";
                    std::cin >> term;
                    std::vector<unsigned> occurrences = binary_search(patients, patientType("", term,0), file_size, [](patientType& first, patientType& second){return first.second_name() == second.second_name();});
                    std::cout << "Found " << occurrences.size() << " occurrences.\n";
                    for(auto a : occurrences)
                    {
                        std::cout << patients[a];
                        std::cout << "\nAt " << a << "\n";
                    }
                    std::cout << std::endl;
                    delete[] term;
                    break;
                }
                case 7:
                {
                    exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Se você mesmo testar, ele dá pau em várias funções, no debug dá `SIGTRAP` várias vezes e do nada, ao pedir um input várias vezes ele crash - *a*. O programa (com as exigências) ficaria lento, mas provavelmente não bugaria. Onde está o erro? Como concertar?

Comment: Qual o backtrace do GDB após o crash?

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal O programa não crasha quando eu debugo ele. Apesar de, mesmo sem breakpoints, ele da SIGTRAP várias vezes, fazendo que o uso do programa seja excessivamente lento. Tente fazer o debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está nos trechos que você aloca uma nova `string` assim:

```
new char[std::strlen(first_name)];
```

Deveria ser:

```
new char[std::strlen(first_name) + 1];
```

Sem o `+ 1` você não está considerando o caractere nulo da string `\0`, que causa nenhum problema em seu programa até o destrutor de `patientType` ser chamado. E isso corre quando você adiciona novos pacientes e quando lista eles.

---

Outros detalhes:

1. Na função `patientType::get()` as variáveis `first_name` e `second_name` devem ser deletadas usando `delete []` (igual você fez no destrutor) e não apenas `delete`.
2. Em `patientType::operator=(const patientType& patient)` você deve verificar e deletar os valores anteriores (ou limpar) das strings antes de alocar novas strings.
3. Quando você faz `return first.second_name() == second.second_name();` você está comparando ponteiros, para comparar o valor das strings use `strcmp()`.
4. E por último, quando você chama a função `binary_search(T* var, T term, unsigned size, BinaryCompare compare_operation)` você está copiando o objeto `T term`. Isso significa que toda vez que você chamar esse função, o compilador chamará o `construtor de cópia` (que você não tem definido), fazendo com que as strings não sejam devidamente alocadas. Uma solução simples é passar o `term` por referência (`T& term`).

---

Outra solução simples para esses problemas é não alocar dinamicamente quando não há necessidade. Por exemplo, na classe você faz:

```
// Na classe:
char* first_name_t; 
char* second_name_t;

// Em get
char* first_name = new char[128];
char* second_name = new char[128];
```

Você pode simplesmente fazer:

```
// Na classe:
char first_name_t[128]; 
char second_name_t[128];

// Em get
char first_name[128];
char second_name[128];
```

E limitar que o usuário não informe nomes maiores que 127 caracteres. Com isso você não precisa mais se preocupar em desalocar. A desvantagem de fazer dessa forma é que cada nome sempre ocupará 128 char, ao invés de ocupar apenas o necessário.

---

Imagino que você não possa usar `std::string`, mas esse é um exemplo de porque deve-se usá-la (te pouparia todo esse trabalho). Mas, de qualquer forma, quando se está gerenciando a memória manualmente, recomendasse verificar se a sua classe atende a [Regra dos Três](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29) (ou Cinco em C++11).

Comment: Eu estava "passando cola" por dinheiro (coisa feia...) para um americano; ele acabou de me falar que posso usar strings: estou salvo!

Comment: @LucasHenrique De qualquer forma, pelo que testei aqui, a solução que postei resolve o problema para char*, mas com std::string é melhor mesmo.